# organizing large python object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python object that represents a connection to a rest api with a large number of endpoints. I need to come up with a strategy to organize hundreds of method calls (right now I am using prefixes on the methods). I would also like to break up the files if that's possible.

I am working in python 2.7

Two give more clear questions -
1) Is it possible to split an object into multiple files in some sort of effective manner in python? Specifically without introducing more complexity?

2) Is it possible to make "submodules" for lack of a better phrase, so

```
my_rest_api.users.create
```

rather than

```
my_rest_api.users_create
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific to get useful answers here...

Comment: edited to reflect specific questions

Comment: If the final object has discretely definable pieces, would writing a bunch of mixin classes, then combining them through multiple inheritance work for your purposes? For the ones that don't make sense instantiated on their own, inherit from [`abc.ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) and define required but unimplemented methods with `@abc.abstractmethod` that would prevent direct construction unless the methods were implemented in the child (directly, or via inheritance from a non-abstract definition in another parent).

Comment: Yes, I screwed up my terminology. I was unaware python had mixins, that's the technology I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the groups as mixins. For example like this:

user_actions.py

```
class UserActions:
    def user_create(...): ...
```

the_api.py

```
from . import user_actions

class TheApi(UserActions, ItemActions, OtherActions, ...):
    # common functionality goes here
```

Then you can call `the_api_instance.user_create(...)` once you have an object created.

Comment: Mixins are what I need, thanks